# Doctrine 2.5 - Always altering table after field collate option changed

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have this Entity:

```
/**
 * @Entity 
 * @Table(name="i18n")
 */
class I18n extends \Framework\Model {
    [...]

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=255, options={"collate"="utf8_bin"})
     */
    protected $string;

    [...]
}
```

After collate option added (`options={"collate"="utf8_bin"}`), console update is altering this table everytime and returning particular SQL query:

> ALTER TABLE i18n CHANGE string string VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;

How to make Doctrine not to alter this table (because there are no changes)?

Comment: "options" is an advanced setting that may cause that behavior, yes. It can be fixed by some effort, but we don't really think it is worth it. You can try patching the DBAL yourself though.

Comment: @Ocramius Ok, so... is there any other way to create tables with other collate in Doctrine?

Comment: Yes, with the method listed above. Just don't expect the schema tool to behave correctly when computing updates. It's a known limitation.